# How to find all possible combinations of an Array of Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have an array of arrays:

```
[
    Array["a", "b"],
    Array["c", "d"],
    Array["e","f"]
]
```

How can I find all possible variants with JavaScript to have an Array like this:

```
["ace","acf","ade","adf","bce","bcf","bde","bdf"]
```

Comment: Cartesian product. Have you tried?

Comment: You can go to the link above and try the solutions provided in answers.